# ELGG: elgg_view_form() path not working

Tags: elgg

I am using ELGG https://elgg.org version 1.8 not 1.9

I created a plugin and wanted to add a form to here:

```
mod/my_plugin/views/default/forms/my_plugin/save.php
```

but this does not work

```
elgg_view_form('my_plugin/save')
```

But if I put the save.php file in

```
/var/www/html/views/default/forms
```

it works

```
elgg_view_form('save')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to login as admin and run "upgrade" or "flush the caches" from the admin control panel